# How to exclude an audio device on Mac?

Tags: macos, display, audio, mojave, hdmi

Every time I plug-in either my HDMI monitor or the HDMI projector on my *MacBook* the playing **music/audio on macOS stops for several seconds**, switches to the plugged device (silently), and **then comes back** to the actual output device that I use (*External Headphones*).

### Use case:

I usually have music in the background; macOS goes to lock/screensaver, turns of the display and disables the external monitor. The music keeps playing.
But when I touch it again the monitor is restored and it takes around 10 seconds to restore. In this time it switches to the monitor HDMI audio, interrupting the audio for several seconds, and then restoring the actual audio device when finished reactivating the monitor.

This is extremely annoying; if the operative system would know to ignore an audio device completely (the external HDMI audio) then this would not happen.

---

### Question:

> In macOS, **how to disable/remove/hide/block an audio device so that is always excluded** and never considered or temporarily activated?

***Note:***
I've searched other questions on stackexchange but apparently nobody has any clue. So I suppose it's impossible via GUI and one needs to `list` and `disable` via some shell/`sudo` Linux/BSD system command.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285311/how-to-stop-sound-output-switching-to-a-monitor-when-it-gets-plugged-in/389302#389302 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395359/removing-a-sound-device-vp3268-4k/395368#395368

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Unfortunately they don't offer any software solution, but just hardware fixes.

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this. Will update if I ever find one.